# Xcode(Swift) - расстояние между textFields в UIAlertController?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift3

Как увеличить расстояние между textFields в UIAlertController в Xcode(Swift)?

```
func showAlert() {
    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter name", message: "Enter name", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "name"
    }

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "address"
        textField.isEnabled = false
    }


    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { action in }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(OKAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В общем надо добавить для каждого из textField эту строку `textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect`, так как для закругленных textField расстояние между ними получается больше. Дальше, чтобы убрать таблицу, которая содержит в себе textFields, надо добавить код после `self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)`

```
func showAlert() {

    let alert: UIAlertController = UIAlertController(title: "Enter name", message: "Enter name", preferredStyle: .alert)

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "name"
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
    }

    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = "address"
        textField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyle.roundedRect
        textField.isEnabled = false
    }


    let OKAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) { action in
        let name = alert.textFields?.first?.text
    }
    let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default) { action in }
    alert.addAction(cancelAction)
    alert.addAction(OKAction)

    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    for textField in alert.textFields! {
        let container = textField.superview
        let effectView = container?.superview?.subviews[0]
        if (effectView != nil) {
            container?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            effectView?.removeFromSuperview()
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения].